# Convey the ability to use an input many times

Tags: user-expectation, input

My site is a legal consultation platform. I am offering an option for visitors to clap answers they like, and they can clap up to 10 times.
Example of the page here:
[image]

How can I convey to the users that they can clap up to 10 times in a user-friendly way?
Thank you.

Comment: Please don't just link your website, it makes your question look like spam. Include your designs directly here in the question

Comment: Oh, is that in the guidelines? I didn't know. Sorry

Comment: Can the user "clap" the same post up to 10 times, or do they get 10 claps per `{amount of time}`?

Comment: I wonder if in the overall site it makes sense that users can clap a single question 10 times. Shouldn't 10 users finding it clappable or 5 different users clapping twice each show higher value than one user clapping 10 times the same answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options you could go with here, and it doesn't just have to be one or the other - why not implement them all.

**Feature introduction**

When a new user loads the page, have a prominent notification somewhere that informs the user about this feature. Something along the lines of:

> "*Did you know... you can show your support by clapping for the answers that you like. You can clap up to 10 times per day.*"

It is important that you get the logic right for determining when this notification is shown. I would suggest look at only showing it to users that have never registered a clap before. Or maybe extend that to also include users that haven't clapped for X number of days. This will serve as a reminder - so you may also want different text for that:

> "*Don't forget... you can show your support by clapping for the answers that you like. You can clap up to 10 times per day.*"

**Keeping track of remaining claps**

You need some method to notify the user how many claps they have remaining. This could be done by simply displaying a brief overlay notification every time they register a clap. For example:

> "*Woo Hoo! Thanks for clapping. You can still clap 9 more times today.*"

Important considerations for this feature:

- Make it subtle. Most users won't need to see it every time, it's just there as a gentle reminder.
- Only show it for a few seconds, maybe 5-10.
- Keep it near to the clap button, but...
- Ensure that it doesn't overlap any elements of the interface that the user might need to look at of interact with immediately afterwards. Find some whitespace to show it.

**Explain when they can't clap anymore**

After the user has used all of their claps, they may still try to clap more. Make it obvious that they cannot do this:

- Make the clap button look disabled. Common approach is to use a light colour (or darker if you have a dark theme).
- Show a notification when the user tries to click the button to inform them that they have no more claps remaining for the day.